# Optional tasks for TFS Task Group

Tags: tfs

I have a task group in TFS but the last task in the group shouldn't be executed by everything that uses it.

I can toggle the enabled checkbox in the task group itself. But then that would apply to every instance of the task group.

[image]

Is there a way to do this for specific instances?

Comment: What version of TFS? Recent versions support conditions for tasks.

Comment: 15.117.27414.0.

Comment: That's TFS 2017 Update 3.1, which should support conditional tasks. If you don't see the ability to specify conditions, then you need to upgrade to a later version in order to access that feature. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

Comment: okay, I think the version I am using is too old. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this for specific instances?

I am afraid there is no such way to do this for specific instances at this moment.

Just as you test, if we enabled checkbox in the task group itself, but this would apply to every instance of the task group. Obviously this is not what we want.

Besides, although TFS supports [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) after 2017 update 3.1:

[image]

**However**, **the custom conditions not support on task groups**. In the task groups:

[image]

And MS replied that:

> It's in the works. It's not a task issue but a service side issue.
>   task group support is coming soon (the main issue is the task group UI
>   is still using the old editor)

Check the [ticket on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/5112) for some more details.

You can add your comment here and track this issue.

Hope this helps.